# Is there a way to config vscode with a Context Window as in Source Insight?

Tags: vscode-extensions

The Context Window is a Source Insight innovation that automatically provides relevant information while you are viewing and editing your source code.  So, is there a way to config Visual Studio with a Context Window as in Source Insight?

Is there a way to config Visual Studio with a Context Window as in Source Insight?